# Validating empty number field in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, jsr

I'm having issues with JSR 303 validation when the user does not enter anything in a box. I want to validate that a field must be a number and > 0. Here is the code

```
@Min(value = 1)
private float price;
```

If a number is entered the validation works fine but if left empty throws `NumberFormatException`

I know that I can change `float` to `Float` and use `@NotEmpty` but I don't want to change the type just because of this simple validation.

Any ideas?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976566/spring-initbinder-bind-empty-or-null-values-of-a-float-field-as-0 for a solution. Basically, you have to extend CustomNumberEditor and inside setAsText you set value to 0 if incoming text is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

**http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html**

It'll restrict user to enter only things, that you are allowing.